# JsScrollpane not updating after adding dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I ran this code to load up xml data into a table, however after the data was loaded, I can't seem to reload the scrollbar. Nothing works, not even running `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();` manually in Firebug.

Here's the code:

```
$("#MenuList").html('<div class=\"menu-activity\">Please Wait</div>');
$.blockUI();

           $.get('venuesxml.php', function (data) {

                $('#MenuList').html("<div class=\"menu-activity\">Showing activity for 13.10.2012</div>");

                $(data).find('marker').each(function () {

                    $('#MenuList').append("<div class='menu-item-red'><div class='typename'>Event</div><div class='eventname'>" +

                    $(this).attr('id') + "</div><div class='venuename'>" +

                    $(this).attr('venue_type') + "</div></div>");

                });

            });

            $.unblockUI();
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

[And here's a live demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/Map.php) Click on "SEARCH" to execute the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialise plugin after adding dynamic content.

Try this:

```
 $(function()
{
    // Initialise the scrollpanes
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();

    // Add some content to #pane2
    var pane2api = $('#pane2').data('jsp');
    var originalContent = pane2api.getContentPane().html();
    pane2api.getContentPane().html(originalContent + originalContent + originalContent);

    // Reinitialise the #pane2 scrollpane
    pane2api.reinitialise();
});
```

[More information can be found here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/less_basic.html)

Comment: Hello, I've read over that and tried putting ` $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
var api = $('.scroll-pane').data('jsp');` at the beggining, and `api.reinitialise();` after `$.unblockUI();` - and nothing happens. No errors either. But if I run `api.reinitialise();` manually through Firebug, I get the error `ReferenceError: api is not defined`.

Comment: This is a working example with dynamic content. Hope this helps. There are 3 key lines I have commented http://jsfiddle.net/ULSR6/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help :) however no luck as well. I still keep on getting the `undefined api` error. I put together a simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTmgd/). The GET code doesn't work there for some reason, but see the code that I commented out. The instant that you make it active, the whole thing breaks. I don't know why, the documentation labels it just like this as well.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle but it's not gonna help because of same origin policy. http://jsfiddle.net/QTmgd/1/. I'll look into this tomorrow if you are not able to solve the issue bu then - cheers

Comment: Thanks Gurpreet. I created a [test file](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/test.php) on my server that I will mess with. That's where you can find the latest code.

Comment: Finally done a working example with dynamic data. I'm using a string variable instead of AJAX but you can easily replace that with your response data. http://jsfiddle.net/QTmgd/2/

Comment: You're the best. I had to move the data into a variable and then reload it, but it works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one must call reinitialise() on the JSP to get it to recognize any data placed in it dynamically...such as after a AJAX call. Looks like there may be timing issues in play here..

```
 var api = $('.scroll-pane').data('jsp');
 api.reinitialise();
```

Or you can use autoReinitialise, which is simply a JS timer that calls reinit.I prefer to use the manual approach, when appropriate.

You will want to read this over.
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html

Comment: Hello, I've read over that and tried putting ` $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
var api = $('.scroll-pane').data('jsp');` at the beggining, and `api.reinitialise();` after `$.unblockUI();` - and nothing happens. No errors either. But if I run `api.reinitialise();` manually through Firebug, I get the error `ReferenceError: api is not defined`.

Comment: Try putting both of those lines after your each loop finishes.

Comment: Search in my code for `/*CHECK THIS*/`, I put the two lines now everywhere and still no result.

Comment: Looking at the DOM, your `$('#MenuList').html("<div class=\"menu-activity\">Showing activity for 13.10.2012</div>");` is killing the JSP container...I think you will need to refactor this to not destroy that, and instead modify another DIV inside.

Comment: For some reason, I can't even initialise `api`. All I do is declare that at the beggining and I already get the error: `TypeError: api is undefined`... however the first thing I do is initialise it like you have shown.

Comment: Okay, I was getting frustrated and thought that the problem may lie somewhere in my code, however I put together a simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTmgd/). The GET code doesn't work there for some reason, but see the code that I commented out. The instant that you make it active, the whole thing breaks. I don't know why, the documentation labels it just like this as well.

Comment: You do realize you have a syntax error here, correct? `$('#MenuList').html("Please Wait");*/`. Also, isn't this fiddle kind of useless because you are not including the JSP script?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it this way.....

```
    //Should it (the #parentContainer) have had a "scroll-pane" class

        $('#parentContainer').jScrollPane()

    $.each(data, function(i, value) {

//Detach scrolling capabilities
        $('#parentContainer').jScrollPaneRemove();

        $('<div/>',{
        class:'anyClass',
        id:'anyId'
        })
        .appendTo(#childContainer);

//Return back Scrolling capabilities to the parent container    
        $('#parentContainer').jScrollPane();            


        ///-> Loop Ends
                });
```

With this, the scrolling capabilities are renewed every time a loop is made....hence the ScrollBar's length will grow or shrink depending on the size of data store in the child container.

Hope that helps....

Ebest